# Special array order by key in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Please could you help me:

i have an array sorted by key:

```
$a['a'] = value;
$a['b'] = value;
$a['c'] = value;
$a['d'] = value;
$a['e'] = value;
```

I need reordeer this by this rule - take one field and put it on first place and another do not change

f.e.

```
$a['c'] = value;
$a['a'] = value;
$a['b'] = value;
$a['d'] = value;
$a['e'] = value;
```

or

```
$a['d'] = value;
$a['a'] = value;
$a['b'] = value;
$a['c'] = value;
$a['e'] = value;
```

Comment: Your question is vague, do you want change the order of the keys so that when you loop through them they are used in the order you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you meant something like this:

```
function get_and_place_first($index, $array) {
    $new_first_element = $array[$index];       // save element you want to have as first
    unset($array[$index]);                     // delete that element from old position
    array_unshift($array, $new_first_element); // place it at the beginning of $array
}
```

You should use it in this way:

```
get_and_place_first('c', $a);
```

and you should get desired effect from your first example. Of course you may want to check if element exists in given array etc., but it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this function from http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2011/09/16/php-swap-array-elements-by-array-keys/

```
function array_swap_assoc($key1, $key2, $array) {
  $newArray = array ();
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == $key1) {
      $newArray[$key2] = $array[$key2];
    } elseif ($key == $key2) {
      $newArray[$key1] = $array[$key1];
    } else {
      $newArray[$key] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $newArray;
}
```

Code example:

```
<?php
  $temp = array('a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B');
  $temp = array_swap_assoc('a', 'b', $temp);
  print_r($temp);
?>
```